# Stop UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer from firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit

Ok, I have a WKWebView with a big textarea inside it, and when I click on it, it fires this UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer and shows the keyboard.

This behavior is correct. Problem is, when scrolling or panning from any other gesture, this UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer is fired and the keyboard shows.

Is there any way to prevent that?

I'm using this to get the problematic gesture recognizer:

```
for (UIView* subview in self.subviews) {
    // here comes the tricky part, desabling
    for (UIView* subScrollView in subview.subviews) {
        if ([subScrollView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"WKContentView")]) {
            for (UIGestureRecognizer* gesture in [subScrollView gestureRecognizers]) {
                if ([gesture isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer")]) {
                    gesture.delegate = self;
                    gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true;
                    gesture.delaysTouchesEnded = true;
                    [gesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:scrollGesture];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doesn't work;

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:

also didn't work

The only thing that worked is returning false on this delegate method:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return false;
}
```

But obviously, now the keyboard will never show..

Resuming, I need the webview to get focus on taps, and to ignore pans and other gestures.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Did you this this one ?

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. The other gesture recognizers are firing correctly. Problem is, this UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer fires first and show the keyboard.

Comment: I want the UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer to fire only when the other gesture recognizers fail. That's why I'm trying it with gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer

Comment: But a touch is not a tap. It fires a soon as the user touches the screen, whereas a drag needs more time to be fired. 
I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you want this way. If you could unbind the touch event and bind a tap instead it would do the job though.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work because I couldn't got WKWebView to focus when removing this UIWebTouchEventsGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I'll think about it tonight, i get back to you tomorrow